# Pass global window scoped variable to child iframe in the same domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

- Why iframe alert undefined if use setTimeout for changing iframe.src attribute?
  Change iframe.src attribute outside of setimeout work.
- How to modify|intercept iframe's eval, Function, Element.prototype.appendChild objects if they are different from parent's window (Element !== parent.Element) ?

---

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IFrame var pass test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        ifel = document.createElement('iframe') ;
        ifel.frameBorder = ifel.style.width = ifel.style.height = 0 ;
        ifel.style.position = 'absolute' ;
        ifel.id = 'id-iframe-x' ;
        document.body.appendChild(ifel) ;
        ifel.contentWindow.Z = 'Y' ; // window changed after load ???
        ifel.addEventListener('load', function () {
            ifel.contentWindow['Z'] = 'Z' ;  // change after load
        }) ;
        // ifel.src = 'iframe.html' ;  // <-- WORK !
        setTimeout(function() {        // <-- NOT WORK !
            ifel.src = 'iframe.html' ;
        }, 3000) ;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IFrame var pass test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        alert(typeof window.Z) ;
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing the value of iframewindow.Z from the parent after the iframe is loaded -- this is correct. Your iframe, however, runs its alert before the iframe is finished loading. You need to define a function on the iframe window and call it from the parent window after the iframe is loaded. You could also try to defer the iframe script, but that'll create a race condition -- it might work now, but maybe not always, especially if you have asynchronous data added from the parent.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks.
`setTimeout(function(){alert(typeof window.Z) ;}, 10000) ;`